# Why are some of my apps not showing in Android Market Developer Console?

Tags: android, console

As of November 24 some of my apps are not visible in my developer console.  Does anyone have any idea why?  they have all been there every other day.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably find help for this issue much faster from here:
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market?hl=en